# Transferring many small files into Hadoop file system

Tags: hadoop, zip, hdfs

I want to transfer too many small files (e.g. 200k files) in a zip file into HDFS from the local machine. When I unzip the zip file and tranfer the files into HDFS, it takes a long time. Is there anyway I can transfer the original zip file into HDFS and unzip it there?

Comment: Why do you it would be faster?

Comment: It takes along time transfering many small files from local machine by the hadoop dfs -put command. I received a couple warning messages because it takes long time and I also be charged more by Amazon. Unzip a file on the same files system should be faster than copy from file system to the other usually.

Answer (score 0):

If your file is in GB's then this command would certainly help to avoid out of space errors as there is no need to unzip the file on local filesystem.

put command in hadoop supports reading input from stdin. For reading the input from stdin use '-' as source file.

Compressed filename: compressed.tar.gz

gunzip -c  compressed.tar.gz | hadoop fs -put - /user/files/uncompressed_data

Only Disadvantage: The only drawback of this approach is that in HDFS the data will be merged into a single file even though the local compressed file contains more than one file.

http://bigdatanoob.blogspot.in/2011/07/copy-and-uncompress-file-to-hdfs.html

Comment: That's right but I want to have the single files on HDFS, I don't wan't to merge them.